# How to check if SQL records are in a specific order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I'm having trouble figuring out how I can check if records on a table are in a specific order.  The simplified table design is essentially this:

```
+------------+----------------+--------+
| ID (GUID)  |   StartDate    | NumCol |
+------------+----------------+--------+
| CEE8C17... | 8/17/2019 3:11 |     22 |
| BB22001... | 8/17/2019 3:33 |     21 |
| 4D40B12... | 8/17/2019 3:47 |     21 |
| 3655125... | 8/17/2019 4:06 |     20 |
| 3456CD1... | 8/17/2019 4:22 |     20 |
| 38BAF92... | 8/17/2019 4:40 |     19 |
| E60CBE8... | 8/17/2019 5:09 |     19 |
| 5F2756B... | 8/17/2019 5:24 |     18 |
+------------+----------------+--------+
```

The `ID` column is a non-sequential GUID.  The table is sorted by default on the `StartDate` when data is entered.  However I am trying to flag instances where the `NumCol` values are out of descending order.  The `NumCol` values can be identical on adjacent records, but ultimately they must be descending.

```
+--------+
| NumCol |
+--------+
|     22 |
|    *20 | <- I want the ID where this occurs
|     21 |
|     20 |
|     20 |
|     19 |
|     19 |
|     18 |
+--------+
```

I've tried `LEFT JOIN` this table to itself, but can't seem to come up with an `ON` clause that gives the right results:

`ON a.ID <> b.ID AND a.NumCol > b.NumCol`

I also thought I could use `OFFSET n ROWS` to compare the default sorted table against one with an `ORDER BY NumCol` performed on it.  I can't come up with anything that works.

I need a solution that will work for both SQL Server and SQL Compact.

Comment: Tables by definition are not sorted. Ordering of data is done during data retrieval. What column are you using as your ordering column? And your desired output doesn't seem to match you sample data. Can you try to explain what you are trying to do here?

Comment: First you need to understand that tables are not sorted by default.   Your question might be valid if you replaced that language with "sorted by StartDate".   At least, that's my best guess as to what you mean.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes I do understand that but I will clarify further.  These records get sorted by StartDate when loaded into a data entry application.  What I'm doing is trying to find where the NumCol values do not line up properly with these sorted dates.

Comment: The order of insertion does NOT mean the table is ordered. Looking at your sample you don't have any rows that don't line up. Seems like forpas has guessed reasonably well at your requirements. Is that answer not what you need?

Comment: @SeanLange I've clearly mis-titled this question since we agree on the point you're making.  The data I posted is highly simplified, checking into the answers now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where numcol > t.numcol and startdate > t.startdate
)
```

Or with row_number() window function:

```
select t.id, t.startdate, t.numcol
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over (order by startdate desc) rn1,
    row_number() over (order by numcol) rn2
  from tablename 
) t
where rn1 > rn2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=605c88997210911cda6c8317b3daa6a0).

Comment: Good way of thinking of the problem.  I wonder, though, how this would perform vs a lead/lag approach.

Comment: @TabAlleman I posted a solution with row_number(). I did not think about this as lead/lag because there is no internal order in the table.

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that the StartDate column is the "internal" (or I would call it "natural") order of the table.   ShawnT's second suggestion is more or less what I had in mind.   Still wonder which performs better.  I'm sure it depends on the table/result size and the indexes on the table.

Comment: @TabAlleman sure, it's just that my first thought was not lead/lag, rather a number for each row depending on date and number. Of course exists is more readable.

Comment: For a very large table, I'm certain that window functions will do better.

Answer (score 3):

This might be easiest:

```
select * from T t1
where NumCol < (select max(NumCol) from T t2 where t2.StartDate > t1.StartDate);
```

The `exists` version is probably better to optimize though.

Using analytic functions you could try this approach which finds breaks in the monotonicity of consecutive rows. It might not return all the rows you're interested in seeing:

```
with data as (
    select *, lag(NumCol) over (order by StartDate desc) as prevNumCol
    from T
)
select * from data where prevNumCol > NumCol;
```

Here's a better solution that's probably not available in both of your environments:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        max(NumCol) over (
            order by StartDate desc
            rows between unbounded preceding and current row
        ) as prevMax
    from T
)
select * from data where prevMax > NumCol;
```