# SQL script to highlight pattern over 2 columns ordered a specific way

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find a way to run some SQL against 2 columns, that will highlight Col1 value where, Col2 value appears not directly next to (sequentially) its Col2 equivalent value, for a given Col1 value.
That last part is important, i.e. Col1 value 4000, has 5921 twice then 8888, so 4000 is valid.

But Col2 notice in bold (I used ** to highlight) that 1011 is alone, instead of next to its 1011 values farther down the list, this is what I need to highlight.

At first I think easy then struggling, been building looping temp tables etc and thinking there must be an easier way to do this, thanks for reading.

Note sample data is small, to get the logic right for solution there is only this below. Solution would highlight for a given Col1 value, and duplicated stragglers, missing from the group

```
Col1    Col2 
4000    5921
4000    5921
4000    8888
4284    6359
4284    6359
4284    6359
4284    5921
4284    **1011**
4284    5921
4284    4970
4284    4970
4284    1011
4284    1011
4284    1011
4284    1011
4284    1011
4284    1011
4284    1011
4284    1011
```

I got this far.. NB: Col1 is PremiseProviderID, and Col2 is CustomerID.

```
declare @PremiseProviderId int;declare @CustomerId int; 
declare @result table
(
    RowID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
    PremiseProviderVersionId    int,
    assigndate        DateTime,   
    EffectiveDate      DateTime,
    effectivedateend DateTime,
    PremiseProviderId int,
    customerid int,comments varchar(max), D2044_RVTransition bit); declare @Spids table (RowID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,PremiseProviderId    int);

insert into @result (PremiseProviderVersionId,assigndate,EffectiveDate,effectivedateend,PremiseProviderId,customerid,comments,D2044_RVTransition)  
select PremiseProviderVersionId,assigndate,EffectiveDate,effectivedateend,PremiseProviderId,customerid,comments,D2044_RVTransition from 
PremiseProviderVersions where   TransactionDateTimeEnd is null order by PremiseProviderId desc, EffectiveDate desc, PremiseProviderVersionId desc;

insert into @Spids (PremiseProviderId) select distinct PremiseProviderId from @result;

declare @i int
select @i = min(RowID) from @Spids
declare @max int
select @max = max(RowID) from @Spids

while @i <= @max begin
     set @PremiseProviderId = (select PremiseProviderId from @result where PremiseProviderId = @i) ;
     set @CustomerId = (select CustomerId from @result where PremiseProviderId = @i) ;

        -- I got to here and realised, must be easier way

    set @i = @i + 1
end
```

The solution is close, but it finds a result with this data, and it should return nothing....Current code gets back, "7542  1136"...

```
(7542,6520,1),
(7542,6520,2),
(7542,6520,3),
(7542,1136,4),
(7542,4778,5),
(7542,4778,6),
(7541,1136,7),
(7541,1136,7);
```

Yet 7541 is OK since its not 7542. So I think the logic is detecting over the 2nd column as a whole, and not resetting once it looks at 7541 col1.

Comment: Its a data analysis thing, data needs to be in a specific order then checked. Its seeking out corrupt bi temporal data

Comment: Fine, but your sample data doesn't show what its ordered by... thats essential for solving this problem. As I note above some of your data is ascending and some is descending - which complicates things.

Comment: did one of the answers help you?

Comment: The order cannot be re-ordered, its esential to the solution. Both columns are primary keys

Comment: You're missing the point the sample data as provided cannot be ordered as you wish without the addition of a further column. Data is not naturally ordered, so to list it in a certain order you must be able to add an `order by` clause - hence why I added one for the answer I gave. I'm not trying to re-order, I'm trying to establish how to get the order you have.

Answer (score 1):

OK this is very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663983/how-to-check-if-sql-records-are-in-a-specific-order) but I appreciate it might be difficult to translate to your situation so here you go:

First you do need a consistent sort column, I imagine you probably do have one, but your data doesn't reflect it.

Secondly, if you assign a row number based on how the data actually is, and a row  number based on how it should be, and any cases where the "actual" row number is greater than the "should be" row number gives you your error rows.

```
declare @Test table (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);

insert into @Test (col1, col2, col3)
values
(4000,8888,1),
(4000,5921,2),
(4000,5921,3),
(4284,5921,4),
(4284,1011,5),
(4284,4970,6),
(4284,1011,7);

with cte as (
  select *
    -- "Should Be" row number
    , row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2 desc, col3 asc) rn1
    -- "Actual" row number
    , row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col3 asc) rn2
  from @Test
)
select col1, col2 --, col3, rn1, rn2
from cte
-- Comment out the following line and uncomment out the additional columns in the select to see the working
where rn1 > rn2
order by col1, col3;
```

Returns

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 4284 | 1011 |

Note setting up your sample data with DDL+DML as shown here makes it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: This appeared to work at first but, it's not, yet its close. I'll edit and show why

Comment: @John when I run your test numbers, I get a result of `7542,1136` which would appear to be correct because its out of sequence. I do think you need to clarify your question because it seems you are wanting something more than your sample data is showing.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want rows where the value is less than the value from the next row.  Just use `lead()`:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             lead(col2) over (partition by col1 order by rowid) as next_col2
      from @results r
     ) r
where next_col2 > col2;
```

Note that your sample data does not conform to the code you've written, which makes the question hard to follow.  This above assumes that `rowid` is the column that specifies the ordering of the rows.

Comment: Its not where value is less, its when value re-appears, within the same row group as first column. The 2nd column must only have one or more values together, for a given left column value

Comment: Is it when the value reappears? Or just appears out of sequence?

Comment: When col2 value reappears, but a given col1, it can reappear in succession but not if it changes, then comes back again